# Android- Make back button switch between tabs (tab navigation actionbar)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity

I'm developing an android app. I have an actionbar in tab navigation mode, and three tabs that call fragments to be replaced in the frameview container.

My problem is: if the user generates a backstack while in one tab and then switches to another tab, if the back button is pressed in this state- then the backstack is popped, but **the tab doesn't change**, which leads to overlapping fragments (backstack fragment which belongs to Tab1 is popped/added, but Tab2 is still selected and so is its fragment).

Is there a way to make actionbar tabs react to the back button in a way that will parallel the fragment backstack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding the tabs to the backstack with names (`addBackStack("MainTab");`) which I chose in the `TabListener`, and then overridden  the `onBackPressed()` method in the activity to recognize when a tab is going to change when the backstack is popped (by getting the top `BackStackEntry`'s name) and used `actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position)` accordingly.

Comment: I solved it. For people who are interested: ``FragmentManager.BackStackEntry bE = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1);
 String nameOfTopBackEntry = bE.getName(); // NAME, you provided with addToBackStack(NAME);``

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `addToBackStack()`, override the `onBackPressed()` method in your activity to customize how you want the back key to behave.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }else {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
}
```